# Beginner's query about CSS positioning

Tags: css

I am trying to move the box by giving CSS selector for `<div>` a relative position attribute and some distance from left and top edge. Problem is it's not working.

Selector is clearly working because if I uncomment visibility attribute, the image is hidden. What's wrong here?

**HTML**:

```
<body>
  <div id="test_logo">
    <img src="http://uselessproducts.weebly.com/uploads/5/2/5/5/5255421/_6517253_orig.jpg" height="100" width="100"/>
    <span id="test_logo_title">test</span>
  </div>
</body>
```

**CSS:**

```css
* { margin:0px; padding:0px; }

html {
    font-family: Verdana, "Lucida Sans Unicode", Arial;
    font-size: 9px;
}

body {
    margin: 9px 0 0;
    background-color: #f37062;
    font-size: 100%;
}

#test_logo {
    /*visibility: hidden;*/
    position: relative;
    left: 100 px;
    top: 200 px;
}
```

**[jsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/r9x5A/1/)**

Comment: Thank you for posting the relevant code. Please do so every time you ask a question.

Comment: As an aside, zeroing out `margin` and `padding` on everything by using the universal selector (*) is pretty heavy handed. You may want to rethink that.

Comment: @steveax, good point. I will take that out.

Comment: @steveax : not heavy handed, if done with intent and understanding of the implications. Personally, I prefer using some tested normalization css specs, such as the one used by http://html5boilerplate.com ... it can really smooth things out when trying to make things work well cross-browser.

Comment: @mori57 given the question title ("Beginners...") I thought it may have been done without understanding the implications. I'm a big fan of normalize.css (which HTML5 Boilerplate uses) but note that normalize.css doesn't employ the universal selector.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need to remove the spaces before `px`:

```css
#test_logo {
    position: relative;
    left: 100px;
    top: 200px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Take the spaces out of the left: and top: specs in #test_logo, and you should be right as rain.

Comment: Wow, that was simple. Actually I just needed to delete space between 100 and px. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was trying to get at, but Michal spelled it out better for you. Glad that fixed your issue!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the modified CSS, I think this should fix your problem, you can adjust the padding of the #logo to meet your space needs from the top and sides.

```
* {margin:0px; padding:0px;}

html{
    font-family: Verdana, "Lucida Sans Unicode", Arial;
    font-size: 9px;
}

body{
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #a37062;
    font-size: 100%;
}


#logo{ 
    padding: 5px;
 }​
```

Heres the link to my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/r9x5A/3/

But as the others stated, the problem you're having is the space between the numbers and 'px' in your css.